# Are there any simple, simulated smart contracts to try out?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, smart-contract-wallets

The barriers to buy, sell and trade cryptocurrencies are fairly low. Anyone can try it now. But very few of the same people can say that they've ever tried to enter into a smart contract.

Are there any good (simulated, therefore free) smart contracts on a simulated blockchain out there to try out so that someone can say that they experienced what it's like?

Beyond simulated contracts, how about actual, cheap ones that are actually on the blockchain? I don't mean smart contract templates to implement. looking for an open contract that is ready, sitting and waiting for a second party to deploy it

Comment: There are some testnets like Rinkeby and Kovan, and some dapps work on one of those testnets. You need to obtain some "fake" eth for them first, but there are faucets for that. Is that what you want?

Comment: try ganache, and truffle boxes